# Can the class have more than one vtable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vtable

say, we have such classes inheritance

```
class A
{
    int a;
public:
    A(){}
    virtual void f1(){}
};

class B
{
    int b;
public:
    B(){}
    virtual void f2(){}
    virtual void f3(){}
};

class C: public A, public B
{
    int c;
public:
    C(){}
    virtual void f1(){}
    virtual void f2(){}
    virtual void f3(){}
    virtual void f4(){}
};
```

And the object:
    `C c;`

In object c we have vptr to one vtable, consists of methods of A+C, and another vtable consists of methods for B. For example x64 build:

- +0:  vtable A+C
- +8:  int a + padding to 8 byte
- +16: vtable B
- +24: int b + padding to 8 byte
- +32: int c + padding to 8 byte

`Class C` have two instance of vtable:

1. for call own virtual methods and overriden methods of A
2. for call overriden methods of B

I'm confused about statement, that one class have one vtable if it is polymorphic

Comment: I fail to identify a question. Do you want to know whether your statemets are true? I believe not.

Comment: You are answering your own question, the answer is yes…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't say how this should be implemented. It's up to the compiler if it does it by using multiple vtables, combines the vtables [in such a way that they can then be "split" again, because `C` must be possible to make into a `B` type object again].

Using multiple vtables is quite a common solution in compilers, so you will see this solution in at least MS's VC++, GNU's g++, LLVM/clang++ and ARM's armcc++. Since I don't know how it works in other compilers, I can't say if other compilers do use this method or not (quite possibly).

To be clear, it is a popular method, but the standard doesn't say how this should be done.

In the future, this may change - someone may come up with a different solution that is better (by some definition of better - e.g. takes up less space, has faster access, etc)

Comment: So, this is quite normal, that there are 4 vtables created: A::vtable, B::vtable, C::vtable1 (override A+own C virtual methods), C::vtable2 (overriden B)?

Comment: Yes, each class that introduces a new virtual function MUST have it's own vtable [or some other construct that allows the virtual function to be identified uniquely to that class - vtable is just the most common solution, the C++ standard does not require any particular solution beyond "it works in the way described" - how the compiler design decides to do that is entirely free to the compiler designer].